# How to limit token generation while "n" users are online?

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-7.0

I need to limit user login up to limited numbers like 5 or 6 max. using outed users does not count.

This is for ASP.NET Core 7 and using JWT.

I tried to create some SQL table for online users but did not found any solutions for this. The main problem is how to get online clients.

Comment: When a user logs in, cache the session information. Then write some conde in "On Athenication" to check weather or not the session is valid and reject or accept the request. Give us some code. We need an example.

Comment: Count how many tokens you have have issued, how long they are valid and decrease the count when they get revoked or elapse. Then check when issuing  a new token if the count is exceeded or not.

Comment: Are you going to require your users to log out? Counting how many tokens you have handed out is easy. Subtracting ones that are not logged on any more will require client-side code to detect if a user navigates away or is inactive (and then code to warn the user "do you want to stay logged in?")

Comment: some of users are offline as they have no activity their token is not expired yet and did not logged out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For user Tracking:
You can create a table in your database to store information about active user sessions. This table should include fields like UserId, Token, LastActivityTime, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE ActiveSessions (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    UserId INT,
    Token NVARCHAR(MAX),
    LastActivityTime DATETIME
);
```

And Then middleware for tracking:
This is  for track user activity and update the LastActivityTime in the database.

```
public class SessionTrackingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public SessionTrackingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, YourDbContext dbContext)
    {
        // Update the LastActivityTime in the database for the current user session
        // You need to extract UserId and Token from the JWT or other authentication mechanism
        var userId = GetUserIdFromContext(context); 
        var token = GetTokenFromContext(context);

        var session = dbContext.ActiveSessions.FirstOrDefault(s => s.UserId == userId && s.Token == token);
        if (session != null)
        {
            session.LastActivityTime = DateTime.Now;
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

Then you can write class for Limiting Concurrent Logins. And ensure that you register the SessionTrackingMiddleware in the Configure method in Startup.cs.

```
app.UseMiddleware<SessionTrackingMiddleware>();
```

Comment: Hello @mehregan can you please give me a clue how detect user goes offline?

Comment: You need an explicit revoke token (aka Logout) method for this. And if a user didn't logout properly you can't really cope with that. You must allow that token he has as long as its not expired/revoked. If you have very long running tokens at the moment you should consider changing that or implement some sort of heartbeat clientside that keeps entries in the here proposed table alive.

Comment: you can use of SignalR. With this technology, the server can be notified immediately when a connection is closed or lost.
In fact, SignalR is a technology like WebSocket for creating real-time connections. Using this technology, you can receive or send information from the client without reloading or connecting to the database.   
`dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR`